# Fatal error: Undefined class constant 'ACTION_FLAG_PRODUCTS_PERMISSION_DENIED' OrderController.php

Tags: magento, themes, magento-1.8, magento-1.9

In magento dash board while opening sales/orders in dashboard its displaying all orders when i click to open it i'm getting this

```
error : " Fatal error: Undefined class constant 'ACTION_FLAG_PRODUCTS_PERMISSION_DENIED' in  /app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/OrderController.php on line 119"
```

and also my sales/invoices is empty in the dashboard

Comment: have you upgraded recently or is this a fresh install?

Answer (score 1):

if you run on older version of magento then add below code in

```
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php
```

Search for "Order flags" in that file.

and in that constants list add one another Constant below it.

```
const ACTION_FLAG_PRODUCTS_PERMISSION_DENIED= 'product_permission_denied';
```

Answer (score 0):

There was an update in Magento 1.8 that changed `viewAction` in `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/OrderController.php` to call `Mage_Sales_Model_Order::ACTION_FLAG_PRODUCTS_PERMISSION_DENIED`.  In Magento 1.7, this wasn't the case.

This change relates to a constant added to `app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php` - `const ACTION_FLAG_PRODUCTS_PERMISSION_DENIED= 'product_permission_denied';` which is on line 359.

I'd guess, in this instance, that you've updated one, but not the other.  Please ensure that both are updated in core.  Alternatively, something is rewriting `Mage_Sales_Model_Order` and hasn't (or has incorrectly) implemented the constant.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have in app/code/local/Mage a folder Sales with some old code. 
Try to rename the folder to Sales_old and test again the orders in admin. If are ok, in local Sales folder is the problem.